# C# to pull all blobs out of database and save to path

Tags: c#, console, blob

Someone on here already pushed me in the right direction. I believe I am on the correct track now to pull all of my blobs out of my database.  The only thing I cannot figure out is (I think) is where to set where it saves to.

Here is all the code:

```
namespace PullBlobs
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=NYOPSSQL05;Initial Catalog=Opsprod;Integrated Security=true;User Id=username;Password=password;";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "Select FileName, FileData from IntegrationFile where IntegrationFileID = @Request_ID";
            cmd.Connection = connection;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Request_ID", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new Guid("EBFF2CEA-3FF9-4D22-ABEF-3240647119CC");

            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Writes the BLOB to a file (*.bmp).
                FileStream stream;
                // Streams the BLOB to the FileStream object.
                BinaryWriter writer;

                // Size of the BLOB buffer.
                int bufferSize = 100;
                // The BLOB byte[] buffer to be filled by GetBytes.
                byte[] outByte = new byte[bufferSize];
                // The bytes returned from GetBytes.
                long retval;
                // The starting position in the BLOB output.
                long startIndex = 0;

                // The publisher id to use in the file name.
                string FileName = "";                     

                // Get the publisher id, which must occur before getting the logo.
                FileName = reader.GetString(0);

                // Create a file to hold the output.
                stream = new FileStream(
                  FileName + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);

                // Reset the starting byte for the new BLOB.
                startIndex = 0;

                // Read bytes into outByte[] and retain the number of bytes returned.
                retval = reader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);

                // Continue while there are bytes beyond the size of the buffer.
                while (retval == bufferSize)
                {
                    writer.Write(outByte);
                    writer.Flush();

                    // Reposition start index to end of last buffer and fill buffer.
                    startIndex += bufferSize;
                    retval = reader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                // Write the remaining buffer.
                writer.Write(outByte, 0, (int)retval - 1);
                writer.Flush();

                // Close the output file.
                writer.Close();
                stream.Close();
            }

            // Close the reader and the connection.
            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();


        }
    }
}
}
```

I think I have every thing altered the way I need it except for where to set the path to save the files to.  Here is the link I found on msdn where I pulled most of this code (and altered it) from.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Dumb question, but are there any actual blobs in there for that request id?

Furthermore, Since you are just reading blobs from the database and writing them to files, why not use BCP?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer of where to put the path.  Make sure you put the @ symbol before the quotation marks.

```
stream = new FileStream(@"c:\dev\Blobs\" + FileName + ".txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
```